# How to overcome : Failed to generate Azure Service package?

Tags: powershell, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services, azure-powershell, cspack

Am trying to enable remote desktop for a Cloud Service and Publish it.

- Added the remote user, and the cscfg is updated.
- Enable-AzureServiceProjectRemoteDesktop ( Prompts for user name and password )
- Imported Publish Settings file and Selected the Subscription to Deploy
- Used **Publish-AzureServiceProject** which is causing the below issue

  **Publish-AzureServiceProject : Failed to generate package. Error: Microsoft(R) Azure(TM) Packaging Tool version 2.5.0.0
  for Microsoft(R) .NET Framework 4.0**
  Copyright c Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
  **cspack.exe: Error**   : CloudServices : Cannot find role entrypoint assembly xxxxxxxxxx. Please
  provide the name of a binary (typically in the root or inside the bin directory) that will be hosted outside the IIS
  worker process.
  ."
  At line:1 char:1

  - Publish-AzureServiceProject
  - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    - CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Publish-AzureServiceProject], InvalidOperationException
    - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.CloudService.PublishAzureServiceProjectCommand

How to overcome this issue? Please advise.

**Please note:** I have Azure SDK 2.5.1

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have entry point dll in service definition .Please refer

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg557552.aspx#EntryPoint